# get StringVar bound to Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a simple GUI program, and need to load default values from an ini file. I've given names to Entry widget and can get it with `nametowidget` method.

However, I can't find a way to access the StringVar bound to the entry widget and update it's value. Using debugger, I can see that StringVar objects dont have a tkinter master, and they dont appear in any widget children. So is what I'm trying to do possible ? Or is there a workaround ?

Below is the concerned function.

```
def load_data(data_file):
    """
    Read an ini file and update related values
    :param data_file:
    :return:
    """
    conf = configparser.ConfigParser()
    try:
        conf.read(data_file)
        for section in conf.sections():
            try:
                container = SECTIONS[section]
                for key in conf[section]:
                    widget = container.nametowidget(key)
                    widget.set(conf[section][key])
            except KeyError:
                pass
    except configparser.Error as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Perhaps store your `StringVar` created in the first place, say a `list`?

Comment: Indeed that could be a solution, but I'd like to find a more `tkinter` way.

Comment: Why can't you store the StringVar in a python variable and change its value anytime you want using the `.set` method.  This is the normal way to do this.

Comment: As I've many input (about a hundred) I'd rather not use every variable directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter widgets have a `getvar` and `setvar` method which can be used to get and set the value of a variable by its name.

You can get the name of the variable associated with a widget using the `cget` method.

Example:

```
var = tk.IntVar()
entry = tk.Entry(..., textvariable=var)
...
varname = entry.cget("textvariable")
value = entry.getvar(varname)
entry.setvar(varname, value+1)
```

Comment: It seems to me that you must assign a value to `var` via `entry` at least once for this to work. Otherwise, I get an error like `_tkinter.TclError: can't read "PY_VAR30": no such variable` in python 3.6.5.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `StringVar` associated to a widget by `widget["textvariable"]`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

a = tk.StringVar()
a.set(0)

b = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=a)
b.pack()

print (b["textvariable"])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Indeed it gives me the StringVar name, but as I can't found the stringvar master, I can't use the `nametowidget` method, so I dont know how to use this name.