# How to change the value in an Entry when validating

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm putting together a program using python3 and Tkinter. I have no previous experience with either of them, but it's slowly happening.

I have several ttk.Entry widgets where the user will input Dates and I would like to use the validation to fix the format of the date. That means replacing what the user typed with a different value. Since there are many of such Entries, I would like to create a single validation that can be used for all of them, but I don't know how to effectively change the text in the Entry after creating the string with the desired value.

The Entries are controlled by their respective StringVar. I'm thinking of finding a way to access the StringVar from inside the validation, but I can't just call it because the same validation is used for all the Entries. I can get the name of the widget during validation with the %W value, then I can get the name of StringVar with `root.nametowidget(W)['textvariable']`, but it returns me something like PY_VAR2, and then I don't know how to go forward.

Comment: You don't actually need the StringVar - `root.nametowidget()` gives you the widget itself, which you can just as easily call `.set()` on.

Comment: I tryed that `root.nametowidget(W).set(newval)` and nothing happened. Should I post my code?

Comment: @jasonharper: the entry widget doesn't have a `set` method.

Comment: The [official tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/entry.htm#M16) says you shouldn't mix validation with a textvariable, and that you shouldn't modify the entry widget value during validation.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56276236/7519434) may be of use.

Comment: @BryanOakley I read the link you gave and realized that I failed to mention that I'm using the ttk.Entry widget. From the oficial documentation for the ttk version, they say "The -validatecommand and -invalidcommand may modify the entry widget's value via the widget insert or delete commands, or by setting the linked -textvariable.", so I'm assuming that whatever was wrong with the original Entry was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the official tk documentation, I manage to solve the issue with the delete and insert commands, instead of trying to set a value to the StringVar. It looked like this:

```
root.nametowidget(wid).delete(0,'end')
root.nametowidget(wid).insert(0, newval)
```

the variable wid came from the %W substitution.

I'm not entirely sure that this solution is ideal, so I welcome any feedback or better alternatives.